# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SCOPE_SUBTREE' macOS

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to connect to my ldap server running on my local machine but it throws the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SCOPE_SUBTREE'`

**What I have done so far:**

Installed ldap library using `pip install python-ldap`

No file by the name of ldap.py in my current working directory thus no overlapping issue

When use the command `print dir(ldap)` following gets printed

```
['HelpFormatter', 'PY3', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'argparse', 'logging', 'main', 'parser', 'subparser', 'subparsers', 'sys']
```

I am working on macOS Sierra. Any help is appreciated and python version is 2.7.10

Comment: Did you name any of your files `ldap.py`?

Comment: @KlausD. i mentioned that i did not name any of my files with ldap.py so no overlap issue.

Comment: Try looking at the directories you have at your PYTHONPATH and your path.
Maybe some of them contain files called "ldap.py".

Comment: @IdanMeyer, already checked that before posting it. No file by the name of "ldap.py" in pythonpath or path as well.

Comment: @HassanAbbas Run the python command: "print ldap.__file__". it will show you the path where the pyc comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You may have pip installed "ldap" instead of "python-ldap"